# Accessing pointer operator of iterator at 65536 position causes segfault

Tags: c++, macos, stl, osx-snow-leopard

Coincidentally, the code seems to fail at the exact amount of the max value of an unsigned short.

```
map<int,vector<string> > backofflist;

for (int k = backofflist.size(); k > 0; k--) // for ($i=$#backofflist;$i>0;$i--)
{
    vector<string>::iterator backofflist_iter;
    int i = 0;
    for (backofflist_iter=backofflist[k].begin();
        backofflist_iter!=backofflist[k].end();
        backofflist_iter++) // foreach $x (@($backofflist[$i]))
    {
        cout << i++ << endl;
        string x;
        try
        {
            x = *backofflist_iter; //foreach $x (@{$backofflist[$i]})
        }
        catch (exception &e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
```

Produces the following output:

```
...   
65532
65533
65534
65535
65536
{segfault}
```

I thought vectors have an unlimited capacity? Is there something I'm missing? I'm writing this program on XCode in Snow Leopard.

Comment: check the max_size attribute on your vector.

Comment: You haven't shown the whole loop; is there anything inside it that adds or removes anything from either `backofflist` or `backofflist[k]`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the code fails at: x = *backofflist_iter;

Comment: @MikeSeymour: adding or removing to maps doesn't invalidate iterators/contents, only changing backofflist[k] anywhere can be a problem

Comment: @ltjax: Removing the current vector from the map will certainly invalidate it; but you're right that removing anything else won't be a problem. In any case, we need to see the rest of the loop; my suspicion is that the vector is changing.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/tc1zp). Please provide the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. http://sscce.org/.

Comment: provide your build script / makefile

Comment: The complete program is a conversion program from an ngram ARPA file to a finite state machine, available at: http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~bromberg/ngramcount/ngram2fsm.html.  There is no make file but the build instruction are available there.  Like I said, the code works just fine for corpora of a certain size or less, but presumably when the input text exceeds a certain overall size, I notice the error.

Comment: Come to think of it, would I want to iterate from size - 1 downto 0? While I have some surface level knowledge of C++ iterators and STL vectors/maps, I know this is the typical convention in a language like Java.  Moreover, I believe the backoff probabilties being stored are intended to be of size size().  This is a 5-gram model I am processing, so k should start at 4.  But it is starting at 3 instead.  That is probably why it works, because the resources required to maintain a 4-gram are far less than a 5-gram.  Still, it is interesting that the code fails at the exact value of i (~65536)

Answer (score 3):

The only solution to this problem is that you inserted a bad `std::vector` into the map prior to this code being called, or otherwise corrupted an existing `std::vector`. This specific section of code is always well-defined behaviour, if not necessarily the behaviour you expect if `backofflist` is not full with the keys you expect.

Of course, the indentation suggests that this is not your whole loop, and that may be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting this line

```
x = *backofflist_iter; //foreach $x (@{$backofflist[$i]})
```

Recompile, then paste the answer. If you have another segfault. print the complete error message.